# Fit Mapbox map to boundaries of dynamic markers

Tags: mapbox

I try to create a map with mapbox, that features dynamic markers. I want the map to automatically fit to the markers, as described here: https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/example/v1.0.0/fit-map-to-markers/. Unfortunately I can't get it working.

The code also contains the feature markers as links (https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/example/v1.0.0/markers-as-links/), which works great – but as JS- and Mapbox-Noob, I can't figure out how to combine both.

The code right now is this:

```
<div class='start-map'>
<div id='map'></div>
<script>
var map = L.mapbox.map('map', 'XXX', {zoomControl: false})
    .setView([-20.1908, -67.5893], 3);

var geoJson = {
    type: 'FeatureCollection',
    features: [

    {
        type: 'Feature',
        geometry: {
            type: 'Point',
            coordinates: [-67.5893, -20.1908]
        },
        properties: {
            title: 'Salar de Uyuni',
            'marker-size': 'small',
            'marker-color': '#fff',
            url: 'http://localhost'
        }
    },

    {
        type: 'Feature',
        geometry: {
            type: 'Point',
            coordinates: [170.2, -43.4764]
        },
        properties: {
            title: 'Franz Josef Glacier',
            'marker-size': 'small',
            'marker-color': '#fff',
            url: 'http://localhost'
        }
    }

        ]
    };

    map.featureLayer.setGeoJSON(geoJson);
    map.featureLayer.on('click', function(e) {
        e.layer.unbindPopup();
        window.open(e.layer.feature.properties.url);
    });


    geoJson.on('ready', function() {
        // featureLayer.getBounds() returns the corners of the furthest-out markers,
        // and map.fitBounds() makes sure that the map contains these.
        map.fitBounds(geoJson.getBounds());
    });


</script>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's corrected code: https://gist.github.com/tmcw/10203442

Issues in this example:

- geoJson is a simple JavaScript object, not a layer, so you can't call methods on it.
- If you're adding custom data to a map, create a new `L.mapbox.featureLayer` rather than using `map.featureLayer`
- If you're calling `.setGeoJSON()` you do not have to wait for the `.on('ready'` event.